# cmd executes but python os.popen and subprocess.call and subprocess.popen and os.system does not execute, why?

Tags: python

here my command to execute in windows cmd through any of one python way.
'net use J: \My-PC\d\SharedFolder'

```
>>> print os.popen('net use').read()
New connections will be remembered.


Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           M:        \\Purushoth-pc\d\marriagePhotosCh 
                                                Microsoft Windows Network
OK           N:        \\Purushoth-pc\d\Materials 
                                                Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.


>>> print os.popen('net use J: \\Purushoth-pc\d\Materials').read()

>>> subprocess.Popen('net use J: \\Purushoth-pc\d\Materials', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
('', 'System error 67 has occurred.\r\n\r\nThe network name cannot be found.\r\n\r\n')
>>> os.system('net use J: \\Purushoth-pc\d\Materials')
2
>>> subprocess.call('net use J: \\Purushoth-pc\d\Materials /persistent:yes', shell=True)
2
>>> subprocess.check_call('net use J: \\Purushoth-pc\d\Materials /persistent:yes', shell=True)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#35>", line 1, in <module>
    subprocess.check_call('net use J: \\Purushoth-pc\d\Materials  /persistent:yes', shell=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command 'net use J: \Purushoth-pc\d\Materials /persistent:yes' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

how can i run this above command through python?
condition: without using any third party modules - mandatory

Please help me to sort out this problem, thanks in advance

Comment: you ran the command TWICE. the first one suceeded and created your `N:` network drive. The second FAILS, because `N:` already exists.

Comment: Have you made sure that `N:` doesn't already exist yet? It seems like if it already exists the command will exit with code 2. This is why the first call returned 2, the second call threw the exception (it'll unless it is 0). You can see the error in the third call. Also [`os.popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen) is deprecated.

Comment: @MarcB I don't think that the first call succeeded. [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) does only the exit code and does not raise an exception if it's ≠ 0.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if the first call succeeded or failed. If the first call failed because `N:` already exists, the second call will fail for the same reason. If the first call succeeded, it will assign `N:`, so the second call will fail again. So either way, it's wrong to do both calls.

Comment: Edited with evidence, please check my query again

Comment: now you all can see that there is no J: disk exist so please tell me any alternate way is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your commands are failing because they contain backslashes, which have a special meaning in Python string literals.  In particular, the "\\" at the start of your network paths is getting turned into a single "\", making them no longer a network path (this substitution is visible in the error message on the last line of your pasted text).

You can either double all the backslashes to escape them (which quickly gets unreadable in cases like this), or put an "r" in front of the string literal to make it a "raw string" which doesn't specially interpret backslashes.  For example: `os.popen(r'net use J: \\Purushoth-pc\d\Materials').read()`